# I need to get output from DBMS_OUTPUT Procedure in the form of table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using below code but i want to get the output from dbms_output procedure in the form of table. can i get the value from below code in the form of table?

```sql
set serveroutput on;

declare
  type t_list is table of zsmart_overall_os%rowtype index by pls_integer;
  zs_smart t_list;
  type e_list is table of mig_mid_bal%rowtype index by pls_integer;
  mig_bal e_list;
begin
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(buffer_size=>NULL);
  select * bulk collect into zs_smart from zsmart_overall_os;
  for i in 1..zs_smart.count() loop
    dbms_output.put_line(zs_smart(i).acct_id||'  '||zs_smart(i).os);
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: What does "in a form of table" mean?

Comment: i mean to say that output as we get from select query in sql .for-example-- select * from table.

Comment: no that is not what dbms_output is for.

Comment: Why don't you just select * from zsmart_overall_os?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly why you want to do this? This sounds like an XY problem where you're asking for help with a solution instead of the actual problem. There isn't likely to be a good solution to this problem since formatting rows as a simple text table is almost impossible in some cases. What would the output look like if one of the columns is a 1MB XML file, how many digits should be displayed, what's the date and number format for different locales, etc. Those decisions are painfully made by SQL clients, IDEs, and export formats like CSV. Most people just use those tools.

Comment: i just want to do that because i want to export my code's output from dbms_output in csv or excel file as we can easily do that in case of select statement by just clicking right click of output and export the data into csv or excel format

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can - kind of - with some formatting. For example:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     TYPE t_list IS TABLE OF emp%ROWTYPE
  3        INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  4
  5     zs_smart  t_list;
  6  BEGIN
  7     SELECT *
  8       BULK COLLECT INTO zs_smart
  9       FROM emp
 10      WHERE deptno = 10;
 11
 12     FOR i IN 1 .. zs_smart.COUNT
 13     LOOP
 14        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
 15              zs_smart (i).empno
 16           || ' '
 17           || RPAD (zs_smart (i).ename, 10, ' ')
 18           || RPAD (zs_smart (i).job, 15, ' ')
 19           || TO_CHAR (zs_smart (i).sal, '999G990D00'));
 20     END LOOP;
 21  END;
 22  /
7782 CLARK     MANAGER           2.450,00
7839 KING      PRESIDENT         5.000,00
7934 MILLER    CLERK             1.300,00

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]**

If it doesn't have to be an anonymous PL/SQL block and `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` option, you could create a function that returns refcursor:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test return sys_refcursor is
  2    rc sys_refcursor;
  3  begin
  4    open rc for select * from dept;
  5    return rc;
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test from dual;

F_TEST
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

Yet another option is to create a function that returns a custom-declared type:

```
SQL> create or replace type t_dept_row is object
  2    (deptno number,
  3     dname  varchar2(20),
  4     loc    varchar2(20));
  5  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type t_dept_tab is table of t_dept_row;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace function f_test return t_dept_tab is
  2    l_tab t_dept_tab;
  3  begin
  4    select t_dept_row(deptno, dname, loc)
  5    bulk collect into l_tab from dept;
  6    return l_tab;
  7  end;
  8  /

Function created.

SQL> select * From table(f_test);

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH             DALLAS
        30 SALES                CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS           BOSTON

SQL>
```

Comment: i know this type of format, Is there any table operator in oracle which can get records as just like simple table from dbms_output?

Comment: There's none, as far as I can tell - not if you want to run it as an anonymous PL/SQL block and use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE. But, if it is OK to create a **function**, there are some options - have a look at edited answer, please.